# Block Facebook chat so that when you log in it appears as disconnected

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I'm looking for some method or trick that allows me to login to Facebook without appearing as connected in the chat, because in addition, it appears the time of my last connection to contacts.

Any functional way to block facebook chat?

**I do not use the option to deactivate because my friends tell them the time of my last session**

Comment: Not possible. If you login, the login servers note that fact. The only way to not log in... is to not log in.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up a URL blocker, maybe via some third-party firewall,
maybe via the router or some other utility.

To block Facebook chat without blocking Facebook access entirely, you need to
block URLs that contain the string `ajax/updatestatus.php`.